# Estado del script regresa [200 OK] pero no solicita nada en peticion asíncrona

Tags: php, ajax

estoy trabajando en lo siguiente, tengo un formulario con el que quiero realizar una petición asíncrona usando AJAX, tengo un archivo .php donde esta el formulario que consta de un **select** que mostrará las materias disponibles para ser añadidas a un profesor, por defecto dice "Materia" pero la misma petición se encargará de dejar en blanco ese select cuando lo llene con la información necesaria. El problema es, que la petición al analizar con el navegador si es lanzada, y dice que su estado es 200, pero al revisar la solicitud no muestra nada, y al ver la respuesta, me muestra error 404. Este es el formulario:

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
   <!-- Card Header - Accordion -->
  <a href="#profesor_materias" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="profesor_materias">
  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Listado de Materias</h6></a>
  <!-- Card Content - Collapse -->
    <div class="collapse show" id="profesor_materias">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="profesor_asignar_materia_form" method="post">
                <?php echo insert_inputs(); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $d->p->id; ?>" required>
                                    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="materia">Materias</label>
                <select name="materia" id="materia" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="">Materia</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Agregar Materia</button>
            </form>
        <hr>
   <div class="wrapper_materias_profesor" data-id="<?php echo $d->p->id; ?>"><!-- Listado con Ajax --></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Este es el .js:

```js
 function get_materias_disponibles_profesor() {

    var form            = $('#profesor_asignar_materia_form'),
    select              = $('select', form),
    id_profesor         = $('input[name="id"]', form).val(),
    wrapper             = $('#profesor_materias'),
    opciones            = '',
    action              = 'get',
    hook                = 'bee_hook';

    if (form.length     == 0) return;

    //Limpiar las opciones al cargar
    select.html('');

    // AJAX
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/get_materias_disponibles_profesor',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 3000,
      data : {
        '_t': Bee.csrf,
        id_profesor,
        action,
        hook
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        wrapper.waitMe();

      }
    }).done(function(res){
     if(res.status === 200) {
      if (res.data.length === 0){
        toastr.error('No hay materias disponibles para el profesor.');
        select.html('<option disabled selected">No hay opciones disponibles.</option>');
        $('button', form).attr('disabled', true);
        return;
      }

      $.each(res.data, function(i, m){
        opciones += '<option value="'+m.id+'">'+m.nombre+'</option>';
      });

      select.html(opciones);
      $('button', form).attr('disabled', false);

    } else {
      $('button', form).attr('disabled', true);
      toastr.error(res.msg, 'Ups!')
    }
    }).fail(function(err){
    toastr.error('Hubo un error en la petición.', 'Ups!');
    $('button', form).attr('disabled', true);
    }).always(function(){
    wrapper.waitMe('hide');
    });  
  }
  get_materias_disponibles_profesor();
 // Aqui estaba la funcion
```

Este es el backend:

```
function get_materias_disponibles_profesor()
{
  try {
    if (!check_get_data(['_t', 'id_profesor'], $_GET) || !Csrf::validate($_GET["_t"])) {
      throw new Exception(get_notificaciones());
    }

    $id = clean($_GET["id_profesor"]);

    if (!$profesor = profesorModel::by_id($id)){
      throw new Exception('No existe el profesor en la base de datos.');
    }

    $materias = materiaModel::disponibles_profesor($profesor['id']);
    json_output(json_build(200, $materias));

  } catch(Exception $e){
    json_output(json_build(400, null, $e->getMessage()));
  }
}
```